# react-router and react-router-dom version mismatch

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
Uncaught Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

I got this error even though i used useNavigate() inside of BrowserRouter.

The problem was solved when the version mismatch was resolved.

Before

```
├─ react-router-dom@6.2.2
│  └─ react-router@6.2.2
└─ react-router@6.2.1
```

After

```
├─ react-router-dom@6.2.1
└─ react-router@6.2.1
```

Did really this version mismatch cause problem or I miss something?

Comment: `react-router-dom` re-exports `react-router` so there's not any compelling need to have both explicitly installed.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I don't know why installed like that.